# Authorize with a specific scheme in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there a way to require a specific **Authorization Scheme** when using the `[Authorize]` Attribute on a Controller in asp.net MVC 4?

I expected something like this (which is totally possible in [.net core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x) btw)

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]
public class MyController : Controller { }
```

Comment: You can inherit Authorize attribute and implement custom logic in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Chetan Ranpariya in the comments I ended up implementing a derived attribute (from `AuthorizeAttribute`). According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2), overriding the `AuthroizeCore` method is the way to do it.

> When overridden, provides an entry point for custom authorization checks.

Here is a working example for future reference

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public string AuthSchemes { get; set; }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (this.AuthSchemes != null)
        {
            string scheme = httpContext?.User?.Identity?.AuthenticationType;
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(scheme))
            {
                return false;
            }

            return this.AuthSchemes.Split(',').Contains(scheme);
        }

        return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    }
}
```

The attribute can be used like this

```
[MyAuthorize(AuthSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType)]
public class MyController : Controller { }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is nothing out of the box that would allow you to write this.
The standard authorize attribute doesn't support this.

But you could write your own attribute and check the claims of the identity coming in.
I used an backport of ASP.NET Core authorization policies to .NET Full framework:  https://github.com/DavidParks8/Owin-Authorization  to write such rules.

How to check of you come from which token?
Normally you will see a claim similar to "idp": "oidc"

How to get the claims?    ((ClaimsPrinciple)User).Claims  ( in Controller code)